# Sql Table values in JSON c#

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, json, httphandler

Hi i have a table with following values

```
Country Count
China      2
India      3
Pakistan   3
```

i want these in JSON as "China" : 2,"India" : 3,"Pakistan" : 3 
I don't want the header Count and Country. I Have tried using ajax and HTTP Handler but no avail

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'CountryRegistrations.ashx',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
                var test = data.Country + data.Count;
                alert(test);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        FilterCountry emp = getCounts();
        // serialize and send..

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        StringBuilder sbJsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        serializer.Serialize(emp, sbJsonResults);

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        context.Response.Write(sbJsonResults.ToString());
    }

    private FilterCountry getCounts()
    {
        FilterCountry fc = new FilterCountry();
        fc.Country = "PK";
        fc.Count = 600;

        return fc;
    }
```

I gives me as PK600 but it should give "PK":600 and how to get these values from database right now im trying to get from hard coded values.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = data.Country + data.Count;
```

Try to change to:

```
var test = data.Country + ':' + data.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `JavaScriptSerializer` then it will will serialize the object in to JSon format like "Key":"Value" that is also based on the object you are passing to `Serialize` method.

Your class "FilterCountry" has two property "Country" and "Count" and assigning values on it.

So it will be serialize like as follows `{ "Country" : "PK", "Count":600 }`

Please go through JSon and serialize examples